# Callback functions in Chapel

Tags: hpc, chapel

I have the following Chapel code.

```
proc update(x: int(32)) {
  return 2*x;
}

proc dynamics(x: int(32)) {
  return update(x);
}

writeln(dynamics(7));
```

I would like to send some kind of callback to `dynamics`, like

```
proc update(x: int(32)) {
  return 2*x;
}

proc dynamics(x: int(32), f: ?) {
  return f(x);
}

writeln(dynamics(7, update));
```

Is this possible?  Are there examples I could browse?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Chapel has [first-class functions](https://chapel-lang.org/docs/technotes/firstClassFns.html) . They are work in progress, at the same time have been used successfully (details are escaping me).

Your example works if you either remove the `:?` or specify the function's type as `func(int(32), int(32))`:

`proc dynamics(x: int(32), f)   // or
 proc dynamics(x: int(32), f: func(int(32), int(32)))`

Comment: Function objects are a reasonable alternative to first-class functions - make a record and define `proc this(args)` for it. `myRecord(args)` will call that.

Answer (score 1):

The same intention may also get fulfilled with passing a ***lambdified*** "*callback*", potentially with an ALAP-associatively mapped callback-wrapper.

```
var f = lambda(n:int){ return -2 * n;};
writeln( f( 123 ) );                                        // lambda --> -246

proc update( x: int(32) ) {                                 // Brian's wish
  return 2*x;
}

proc dynamics( x: int(32), f ) {                            // Vass' solution
  return f( x );
}
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------    
writeln( dynamics( 7, f ) );                                // proof-of-work [PASS] --> -14

var A = [ lambda( n:int ){ return 10 * n; },                // associatively mapped lambdified-"callbacks"
          lambda( n:int ){ return 20 * n; },
          lambda( n:int ){ return 30 * n; }
          ];
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------    
writeln( dynamics( 8, lambda(i:int){ return    f(i); } ) ); // proof-of-work [PASS] --> -16
writeln( dynamics( 8, lambda(i:int){ return A[1](i); } ) ); // proof-of-work [PASS] -->  80
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
forall funIDX in 1..3 do
       writeln( dynamics( 8, A[funIDX] ) );                 // proof-of-work [PASS] -->  80 | 160 | 240
```

The whole [TiO.run](https://tio.run/##lZJLa8JAFIX38ysOboxi1ESxYmghpZvuCkIphCzGPHAwzoRJ4gOb356OjTEW0poOw6zufOfec663pnEQFcWOSoR4RES3K59qfMF42jtBBmkmOXQTfXArt8hesjSIuIZQg2FO0EPPQsszGl3w0PUnxZzOCIml8JDFPk0DDYcFlKw2MRUVpza8Z8ko7ybYs2RNULVr9g8WyS9w/8jplnnJLX6gZr2joODvNEm6SESUpUzwGq9GP6ixzwpXO2qVhxJ@3xaloBoUoa7uXsgNnDd7uXRLc4wpIedMbJWJU6WC71hQ52KMv3NBPmiAq@6Fx2jKdkF0xJbGceCXJBaywNc7Ho2iFfU2SYfUH3@TMq9SLYonVfFNrWs12jUfVBT2c@fUCTWmbMxLN/@2a/Yvtu0Ybls25mNCQiGVWQgz/vryobYIxnA4gS@q@ZrFbaf84Dbvwx1VfMKYnV9zOi6KLw) online-IDE mock-up [code is here](https://tio.run/##lZJLa8JAFIX38ysOboxi1ESxYmghpZvuCkIphCzGPHAwzoRJ4gOb356OjTEW0poOw6zufOfec663pnEQFcWOSoR4RES3K59qfMF42jtBBmkmOXQTfXArt8hesjSIuIZQg2FO0EPPQsszGl3w0PUnxZzOCIml8JDFPk0DDYcFlKw2MRUVpza8Z8ko7ybYs2RNULVr9g8WyS9w/8jplnnJLX6gZr2joODvNEm6SESUpUzwGq9GP6ixzwpXO2qVhxJ@3xaloBoUoa7uXsgNnDd7uXRLc4wpIedMbJWJU6WC71hQ52KMv3NBPmiAq@6Fx2jKdkF0xJbGceCXJBaywNc7Ho2iFfU2SYfUH3@TMq9SLYonVfFNrWs12jUfVBT2c@fUCTWmbMxLN/@2a/Yvtu0Ybls25mNCQiGVWQgz/vryobYIxnA4gS@q@ZrFbaf84Dbvwx1VfMKYnV9zOi6KLw).